# Regex matches fails in google app engine

Tags: java, regex, google-app-engine, gradle

I'm trying to do some regex matching for greek characters.
The following code returns false when tested in google app engine (in the local development server with Android Studio) but returns true when tested in Eclipse as a normal Java project.

In both cases Java SDK 7 is used.

```java
String text="ααα";

String regex="^α{3}";

boolean result=text.matches(regex);

System.out.println(result);
```

In `build.gradle` i've added: `jvmFlags = ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"]`

and in `appengine-web.xml`:

```xml
<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as a side note: when using `String#matches()` you don't need to add `^` and `$` since the method will try to match the entire string anyways, i.e. it is like an implicit `^exp$`.

Comment: Just curious: since you are using `matches`, anchors are redundant - remove `^` and retry (i.e. with `String regex="α{3}";`).

Comment: "false" for android studio and "true" for eclipse.

Comment: Some more testing:   System.out.println("ααα".matches("α{3}"));  <--FALSE
        System.out.println("ααα".matches("α+")); <--FALSE
        System.out.println("ααα".matches("α.*?α")); <--TRUE

Comment: I guess it is a "WAT?!" candidate :) Please check if you really have 3 same letters `α` without any diacritics, or invisible characters in between by pasting your *exact* input into [this converter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Comment: @stribizhev.Thanks a lot for your replies. I've checked the converter and there are only these 3 letters present.

Comment: This intrigued me so I just quickly made a bare bones test app using Maven, App Engine SDK 1.9.27 and Java 7... but I can't reproduce your problem.  I'm not sure if that helps but maybe it's a gradle thing?

Comment: @ tx802. I've also tried it with App Engine SDK 1.9.27. Same problem here. I'll try to see if it is a gradle-related issue.